# Manager does not work on Tomcat 6 but works on v7

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, application-server

I want to use the Tomcat manager with the Maven plug-in but it does not seem to work; I have changed the `tomcat-users.xml` file to contain:

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="admin" password="password" roles="admin,manager,manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

When trying to access `http://localhost:8080/manager/` I get `HTTP Status 404 - /manager/`/ Other applications work; what is interesting is that this only happens on Tomcat 6; on Tomcat 7 the manager works fine (the problem is my project that only works in Tomcat 6).

ROOT and manager folders are present in webapps folder (I have tried with a fresh downloaded Tomcat 6 to make sure they  are not corrupted anyhow).

The only thing I haven't done is to set the environment variables for CATALINA_HOME (&others) but I do not believe that this might be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running Tomcat 6 use:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html
```

More info [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html).